# Responsive menu button affecting header alignment (Angular Material)

Tags: angularjs, button, mobile, header

I have a responsive Angular Material based app. When it switches to mobile view, a burger menu icon appears in the top left corner (in the md-toolbar).

My problem is that it appears in the document flow, which pushes the header div to the right, when I want the header div to be centred regardless.

How do I fix this?

EDIT... (code snippet)

```
    <md-toolbar layout="row">

        <md-button class="menu" ng-click="ul.toggleList();" hide-gt-sm>
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="menu"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <h1>Soccer Sauce (LT5)</h1>

    </md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal viable code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help debug the issue.

Comment: Sorry, code snippet included - see edit.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Use a parent div inside your toolbar like this:

```
<md-toolbar>
<div layout="row">
    <md-button flex="10" class="menu" ng-click="ul.toggleList();" hide-gt-sm>
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="menu"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <div flex="90" layout="row" layout-align="center">
        <h1>Soccer Sauce (LT5)</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Surely this would center both the button and the siteheader(?), whereas I want the burger menu on the left and siteheader central...